# WebRtc not working on cross-browser

Tags: php

I am using https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RTCMultiConnection/MultiRTC/
on my PHP website.
After implementing on my website everything works fine but I am stuck on one problem which is while we call mozilla to chrome or vice versa, after share webcam one of the user eventually and automatically left the room.
video flashes for one or two seconds

Comment: can any one help?

Comment: Please open RTCMultiConnection issues here: https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/issues

Comment: Hi Muaz Khan, thanks for reply.
I managed to work on cross browser. :)
but on my website 
room are not joining also I tested on your demo its also not joining the rooms.
please follow your demo link :

https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RTCMultiConnection/MultiRTC/